# finding a series with a special limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

i would like to find the coefficients $a_n$ so that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2) a_n (t-1)^n=1-\frac{1}{t}$$. I tried finding it with wolfram alpha but for some reason i do not find the right coefficients. is there a general approach to finding them?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left-hand side is a series expansion at $t_0=1$. We can expand the right-hand side at $t_0=1$ and compare coefficients.

> We obtain using a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)* at $t_0=1$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1-\frac{1}{t}}&=1-\frac{1}{1+(t-1)}\\
> &=1-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j(t-1)^j\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}(t-1)^j}
> \end{align*}

Coefficient comparison with the left-hand side $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)a_n(t-1)^n$ gives
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_0}&\color{blue}{=0}\\
\color{blue}{a_n}&\color{blue}{=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1}
\end{align*}